# which json format is most appropriate for sending http post request in vc++

Tags: json, visual-c++

i am implementing post request with json data. i already implementing http request protocol. i am having key pair value.. which json format should i use. here are some json format i have. which is most appropriate for sending data to web page. if anyone have better format than this for vc++ than kindly suggest me.. here are few format for json.

```
 char *JsonData = "[{ 'Name': 'Rushi'}]";

   char *JsonData = "[ { "key": {'Name'}, 'val': {'Rushi'}  }]";

    char *JsonData = "{ \"Name\": \"Rushi\" }";


   char *JsonData = ("{ \"Name\": \"Rushi\"}");

    char *JsonData = "[{ \"Name\": \"Rushi\" }]";
```

please suggest me appropriate json format.

Comment: have you looked at casablanca? http://casablanca.codeplex.com/